# Create landing page multiple language laravel 5

Tags: laravel, multilingual

i want to create a landing page with laravel. This web has multiple language. And english as default language. and im using laravel 5.8 version.

for example if we access to About Page
hxxps://myweb.site/about -> default lang
and
hxxps://myweb.site/fr/about -> use french lang
hxxps://myweb.site/en/about -> use english lang

anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve multiple language landing page using Laravel's localization. You can create string for every language you can use. Those strings are located in `resources/lang` directory. Let's say, for example, you want to use french language. Inside this directory, create a new directory called `fr`, and inside that directory, create `messages.php` file, that would look like this:

```
<?php

return [
    'hello' => 'Bonjour'
];
```

Now you need to configure or determine what language should be used. The default language for your application is stored in the `config/app.php` configuration file. You may modify this value to suit the needs of your application. You may also change the active language at runtime using the `setLocale` method on the App facade:

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    //
});
```

When you configure your config, you can then retrieve the string you previously defined by using the `@lang` directive in your `blade` view, like this:

```
@lang('messages.welcome')
```

This was the simplest example of using language files. Hope it can lead you in right direction. Read more about it in Laravel's official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/localization).

Comment: its only work if you access the web with segment locale (hxxps://myweb.site/en/page),,  how about hxxp://myweb.site/page ?